# Delphi 7, TFileStream cant open files with special characters

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

This line:

```
TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
```

drops an exception if the filename contain something like **ñ**

Comment: My crystal ball tells me it's the [`ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681382(v=vs.85).aspx#ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) one. And it's because you're not using Unicode Delphi.

Comment: and how to use unicode? :)

Comment: You could use the ansi `TFileStream` by passing `GetShortPathNameW` to it (as long as the input file name is stored correctly as `WideString`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are, ultimately calling `CreateFileA`, the ANSI API, and the characters you use have no ANSI encoding. The **only** way to get beyond this is to open the file with `CreateFileW`, the Unicode API.

You might not realise that you call `CreateFileA`, but that's how the Delphi 7 file stream is implemented.

One easy way to solve your problems is to upgrade to the latest Delphi which has good support for the native Windows Unicode API.

If you are stuck with ANSI Delphi then you still need to call `CreateFileW`. You can do this to create a file handle. You'll need to pass a UTF-16 string to that API. Use `WideString` to store it. You'll also need to get the filename from the user in UTF-16 form. Which means a call to `GetOpenFileNameW` or `IFileDialog`. Create a stream by passing the file handle to `THandleStream`.

To make all this possible you would use the TNT Unicode libraries. They work well but will impose a big port on you.

Frankly, the right way forward is to use modern tools that support Unicode.

Comment: Using UTF-16 based APIs is best, yes. But `CreateFileA()` *CAN* open a filename with Unicode characters in it, as long as they are encoded in Windows' default ANSI codepage. Place the Unicode characters in a `WideString` and cast it to `AnsiString` (the RTL converts using the default codepage) or use `GetOpenFileNameA()`, and then pass the resulting ANSI filename to `TFileStream` or `CreateFileA()`.  It works fine, as long as the default ANSI codepage supports the Unicode characters in question.

Comment: @Remy It appears that the codepage in question cannot encode this character.

Comment: @David - I'm curious how you have determined this ?

Comment: @Deltics Presumably if the characters could be encoded then the file would be opened.

Comment: @David - except that nowhere has the OP indicated that they have *tried* the codepage conversion on the filename and found that it did not work.  Someone may *speculate* that the codepage in question may not support the required characters, but nowhere is this "apparent" (not yet at least). An uninformed comment masquerading as a seemingly confirmed finding, like this, could dissuade the OP from even trying and possibly missing out on a solution to their problem (albeit perhaps not as ideal as migration to Unicode, but likely more practical in the interim).

Comment: @Deltics In 2015 I think it is misleading to advise somebody to code against the ANSI Win32 API. I also wonder what this conversion is that you think is somehow missing. After all the user is calling `TFileStream.Create`. If they don't have an ANSI string encoded in the default code page, what do they have? If it's a `WideString`, then the encoding will happen implicitly. I honestly cannot understand why you are endorsing ANSI.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the TntUnicode units to have UTF8 support under Delphi 7.
Add TntClasses to your Uses and make the call like this:

```
TTntFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
```

Make sure that fileName is widestring.

Here you can get a copy of TntUnicode:
https://github.com/rofl0r/TntUnicode

Comment: WideString is UTF-16 rather than UTF-8.

Answer (score 2):

UTF16 can be thought of as a codepage, just like all of the possible ANSI codepages.

As Remy mentions in his comment, assuming your ANSI codepage supports the required characters in your Unicode string you simply have to convert that Unicode version of that string to the equivalent ANSI codepage version.

The Delphi compiler can take care of a simple conversion for you automatically, which you use simply by casting a **WIDEString** (UTF16) to an (**ANSI**)**String**:

```
const
  WIDE_FILENAME : WIDEString = 'fuññy.txt';
var
  sFilename: String;
  strm: TFileStream;
begin
  sFilename := String(WIDE_FILENAME);

  strm := TFileStream.Create(sFilename, fmOpenRead);
  // etc
end;
```

This works perfectly well even on (e.g.) Delphi 7.  The only caveat is that the codepage involved (the system default) must support the extended characters in the Unicode string.

**NOTE:** The above code uses the String type rather than **ANSIString** explicitly.  On Delphi versions where **String** is **ANSIString**, this has the required effect but also is portable to versions where **String** is **UnicodeString** (should you upgrade your version later).

If you use **ANSIString** explicitly in this case, the result will be a **double** conversion if/when you upgrade:

```
// Unicode compiler using ANSIString type....
var
  sFilename: ANSIString;
begin
  sFilename := ANSIString(WIDE_FILENAME);            // Codepage conversion from UTF16 to ANSI
  strm := TFileStream.Create(sFilename, fmOpenRead); // Will implicitly convert *back* from ANSI to WIDE
```

versus

```
// Unicode compiler using String type....
var
  sFilename: String;
begin
  sFilename := String(WIDE_FILENAME);                // String type conversion from WideString to UnicodeString
  strm := TFileStream.Create(sFilename, fmOpenRead); // No further conversion necessary
```

Answer (score -1):

Best solution is to go Unicode, but if that is not an option, you can still solve the problem.

In Windows you can set what codepage to use for non-Unicode programs. Just change it to support the correct language (Spanish?). Then the code should work.

- `Windows 7`: Control Panel > Region and Language > Administrative > Language for non-Unicode programs
- `Windows XP`: Control Panel > Regional and Language > Advanced > Language for non-Unicode programs

Comment: This isn't very practical though is it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan This is the actual answer to his problem. The other answers are work arounds.

Comment: No. The solution to the problem is to use Unicode, the native character encoding of Windows, and stop using ANSI Win 98 back compat. Changing your language every time you need to read a file is not going to work out.

Comment: SO is for code problems. The answer to a code problem can never be to buy new software! Despite from that I totally agree that he should upgrade because Unicode is a lot easier to work with.

Comment: If the asker doesn't want to upgrade to a modern Delphi then they can use the TNT Unicode library. But I also disagree with your assertion that using better tools is never a solution.

Comment: Btw, the revenge downvote was misplaced. I have not voted anywhere in this topic.

Comment: ;-) I was sure it was you, sorry about that. Right now I cannot undo it?

Comment: Why are you revenge downvoting?

Comment: You neglected to understand my point and turning it into a discussion of words. My answer is as correct as yours, just with different views and perspectives. I thought you revenge downvoted my answer.

Comment: I don't think much of your answer. Imagine if the user wants to open one file that uses characters from cp1251, and then another file with characters from cp1252. Your solution isn't very practical. Code pages were a crutch designed for Win95 which did not support Unicode.

Comment: It depends on the situation. When our software was built with Delphi 7 it was translated to 30 different languages (including asian languages). A user would never use more than one language, but as a developer you need to test all languages. For this situation my answer fits perfectly well. Switching to Unicode is a better long-term solution but also takes more time.

Comment: well, if that is your answer you better to present the code that analyses te filename then switches the codepage which topicstarter would use in his program  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd374051(v=vs.85).aspx  or at least the code to check the if the program is working under suitable locale and asking user to change it if it is not.