# How to convert ANSI string filename to windows filename

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-7

I have written this function to create files on my system (Windows XP):

```
procedure TGrammar.AddFile(var filename: string);
var
newFile : TextFile;
begin
  if not fileexists(filename) then
    begin
      System.AssignFile(newFile, filename);
      System.Rewrite(newFile);
      WriteLn(newFile, '');
      System.CloseFile(newFile);
    end;
end;
```

String which I pass is:
`"a:/7/40/pÄ›knÃ½"` which corresponds with utf8 `"a:/7/40/pěkný"`.
When the file is created on my filesystem it looks like this: `"pÄ›knĂ˝"` instead `"pěkný"`.

It is not clear to me how to convert the string so it is written correctly on the system. How to correct the problem?

Notice: I use Delphi 7

Comment: You are likely using a non Unicode Delphi version. In which case you will need to call `CreateFileW` passing a UTF-16 encoded string. You can convert between UTF-8 and UTF-16 a variety of ways. I don't feel able to advise you on the best way because I can't see where the UTF-8 data is coming from. Perhaps it would be better just to use UTF-16 instead of UTF-8, or perhaps the UTF-8 arrives from an external source. You won't be using legacy Pascal I/O. You'll want to use streams, for instance `THandleStream`. Better would be TnT Unicode controls. Or upgrade to "modern" Unicode Delphi.

Comment: I have a txt file with utf8 text. I read the data line by line using TStingList.LoadFromFile then I parse all words in it and I create the files.I work with D7 which reads the string in ANSI. I don't think that CreateFileW is part of D7.

Comment: Here is solutions how to create file with unicode filename with non-unicode Delphi version: [Delphi 7, TFileStream cant open files with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30965496/delphi-7-tfilestream-cant-open-files-with-special-characters)

Comment: `CreateFileW` is available in Delphi 7. UTF-16 is not the same as ANSI. I recommend that you learn more about Unicode. We can't teach you that here. You have to do research on that. Start here: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/

Comment: Does your first comment mean, that the data written on my system are in UTF-16 encoding?

Comment: No it does not. But the Windows API works with UTF-16 encoded text. So you need to call `CreateFileW`. Have you read Joel's article yet?

Comment: No. I mean have you read the article to which I linked which will fill in important details regarding Unicode.

Comment: I tried to modify my code like this: `    filename := 'a:\\7\\40\\pÄ›knĂ˝';
    w := UTF8decode(filename);
    H:= CreateFileW(PWideChar(w), GENERIC_READ,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE or FILE_SHARE_READ, nil,
    OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, 0);
    if H = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
      raise Exception.Create(Format('Oops - error opening disk: %d', [GetLastError]));
` But I got exception error opening disk. Did I written the code correctly?

Comment: Clearly not. What does `GetLastError` return?

Comment: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND ... I stiil get this error even if I change the ansistring to 'A:\\pÄ›knÃ½'; (then I convert it to widestring so it should be OK).

Comment: Well, that error code tells you that the file does not exist.  Your code attempts to open the file for reading.  Let's assume that the error code is accurate.  The file with the specified name does not exist. Why are you opening the file to read? And why are you passing those sharing flags?

Comment: Pass `GENERIC_WRITE` for `dwDesiredAccess`. Pass `0` for `dwShareMode`. Pass `CREATE_NEW` for `dwCreationDisposition`. Remove the test for `FileExists` because `CREATE_NEW` handles that for you.

Comment: Yet I have one error  ERROR_FILE_EXISTS seems that this occures when the file already exists.

Comment: Yes, that's clearly documented in the documentation for `CreateFile`, regarding the `CREATE_NEW` flag for `dwCreationDisposition`. Your job is to chcek for `ERROR_FILE_EXISTS` and then respond to that. That's the equivalent of the `else` part of your `FileExists` test in the code in the Q. Please read the documentation, especially for `CREATE_NEW` and I am sure you will understand.